# Render dynamic pages stored in database

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, actioncontroller

I want to store pages in the database that are dynamically added/edited/etc. Along with the page title and content I also supply which layout to use and a controller name and view name in order to support the instantiation of models which the view (e.g. text field in the pages table) will use.

I'm having trouble rendering the text from the database and having the layout still be used.

```
class AboutController < BaseController
  def index
    @model_data = ...

    render_dynamic_page("about", "index")
  end
end

class BaseController < ApplicationController
  layout "public"

  def render_dynamic_page(controller_name, action_name)
    page = Page.where("`controller_name` = :controller_name AND `action_name` = :action_name", { :controller_name => controller_name, :action_name => action_name }).first

    render :layout => page.layout_name, :text => page.content
  end
end
```

I'm using `:text` here and I've also tried `:inline` but both seem to not render the content within the layout.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Normally if you want to allow users to edit the html pages in a rails application, and store the pages in a DB, the standard way is to use the template language called `liquid`.

It allows you to define dynamic content, ideal for CMS systems in rails, I think its better you have a look first.

following are some important links

[liquid home page](http://liquidmarkup.org/)

[rails cast about liquid](http://railscasts.com/episodes/118-liquid)

[git hub page](https://github.com/Shopify/liquid)

and there are lots of resources in SO itself. :)

Comment: Thanks, I'll check it out. I'm still curious how to make it work w/out an additional library - so do tell if you know.

Answer (score 0):

I was so close - I just had to switch the order of the parameters to the `render` method:

```
render :inline => page.content, :layout => (page.layout_name || "public")
```

I also added a default layout to use `public` in case a `page.layout_name` was not specified in the database. The other thing that's worth mentioning is the difference between `:text` and `:inline` - only `:inline` seems to actually "process" the content as if it were an ERB whereas the `:text` option just literally outputs the raw text.

**Note :** I ended up creating an ERB for each page using `ERB.new(page.content)`, caching the list of dynamic ERBs and then pulling the pre-rendered ERB from the cache and displaying it using:

```
render :inline => the_cached_erb.result(binding), :layout => (page.layout_name || "public")
```

There is still some weird behavior going on but I think it will work in the end.

Answer (score 0):

Just FYI and for greater tools variety you may want to check out Mercury editor:

http://jejacks0n.github.io/mercury/

https://github.com/jejacks0n/mercury

http://railscasts.com/episodes/296-mercury-editor

Comment: I want simply to store my views in the database. I've accomplished this, almost, by writing my own (simple) `DbResolver < ActionView:Resolver` - but I'll checkout your suggestion, too.